# remove first class with jQuery while cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write a simple function to clone a field:

Online Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5yVPg/

#### HTML:

```
<div id="main">
       <a id="add-input" href="#">+ add</a>

       <p class="child">
         <input type="text" name="user[]" />
         <a href="#" class="icon-delete">delete</a>
       </p>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-input').click(function () {
        var newField = $('.child').clone()
        newField.toggle().attr('class', '')
        registerRemoveHandlers(newField, '.icon-delete')
        $(this).parent().append(newField)
        return false
    })
    function registerRemoveHandlers(el, class) {
        $(el).find(class).click(function () {
            $(this).parents('p:first').remove()
            return false
        })
    }
})
```

I want to remove the delete icon from the first input, I tried :

```
$('p.child .icon-delete:first').css('display','none')
```

But the delete icon being not displayed for all input.

PS: If I could optimize the codes above I'll be happy :)

Comment: when you are calling this $('p.child .icon-delete:first').css('display','none') ?

Comment: the same result, in the end and in the begin

Comment: You can add HTML, but you need to use Markdown so that the HTML will be escaped for you. Use the code button (the `{ }`) on the editor or `ctrl` + `K` to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this instead:

```
// Keep a single clone of the original
var clonedField = $('.child').clone(),
    main = $('#main');

// Add in the delete <a> to the cloned field
$('<a>', {
    text: 'delete',
    class: 'icon-delete',
    href: '#',
    click: function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    }
}).appendTo(clonedField);

// Clone the cloned original and append it back to the list
$('#add-input').click(function() {
    main.append(clonedField.clone());
    return false;
});
```

The code is simpler and easier to understand then what you have there, and should work as you expect it.

See it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZFh6/

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://aseptik.net/demo/remove-first-class-with-jquery-while-cloning

```
$(function() {
    $('#add-input').click(function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" name="user[]" /> ' + 
          '<a href="#" class="icon-delete">delete</a></p>').appendTo('#main');
    });

    // just for sake...
    $('.icon-delete').live('click',
    function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,
        function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

**gotchas:**

1. why you are cloning?
2. why you are placing the delete button in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

i think this will do the trick.......`$('p.child .icon-delete:first').css('display','none')` is hiding all `.icon-delete` which is child of `p.child`. and in your case all `p.child` is a child of `.icon-delete`

```
$('p.child:first .icon-delete').css('display','none')
```

Comment: when you are calling this $('p.child .icon-delete:first').css('display','none')

Comment: i think because of cloning it's happening

Comment: i think first clone the .child without .delete-icon...then add this in that cloned object.

Comment: I don't want to write too much lines :(

Comment: i think it will be same no of lines of code..because you have to remove one line from one place and paste line to another place...any ways it's upto you..goodluck

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add-input').bind('click',function ()
{
    var newField = $('.child').clone();
    newField.toggle().attr('class', '');
    registerRemoveHandlers(newField, '.icon-delete');
    $('p.child:last').after(newField); //append after not cloned child

    newField.parent().children('p').find('a').show(); //show all 'delete' label
    newField.prev().find('a').hide(); //hide label from the first child which is right the one before our clone

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K7F5K/