# Dynamically load in a <form:input> from button click event - Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

I am trying to add an input field upon a button click, I am getting an exception as follows: `.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'name' available as request attribute`
I assume it is doing this as it can not guarantee that there is an object to bind the result to upon a submit? Is there any way around this? or is it not possible for me to load in a  field dynamically?

**This is my HTML, I am just playing with the concept at the moment so its the bare minimum**

```
<input type="button" id="more_ingredients" onclick="add_ingredients();" value="add more">
<form:form commandName="newIngredients" id="form">
   <div id="wrapper">
      <form:input path="name"/>
      <form:input path="amount"/>
      <form:input path="unit"/>
      <br>
      <form:input path="name"/>
      <form:input path="amount"/>
      <form:input path="unit"/>
      <br>
   </div>   
   <form:button type="submit">Submit</form:button>
</form:form>
```

**This is my JS**

```
function add_ingredients() {
   document.getElementById('form').innerHTML += '<form:input path="name /> <form:input path="amount"/> <form:input path="unit"/>';
   //The exception is being triggered by the above line, if I remove the 'form:' tag, the error will disappear.  
}
```

I can dynamically input a standard input field but then I can not assign a path to it for my controller.

**Edit --**

if I wrap the  in a  with the target object declared the error goes away like so:

```
<form:form commandName="newIngredients"> <form:input path="name" /> <form:input path="amount"/> <form:input path="unit"/></form:form>
```

This removes the error but the input inside the automatically generated inputs do not pass through to the controller.

Comment: Is the exception triggered even when you set different names for your input fields (such that you don't have duplicate names )?

Comment: yes, it is.
The duplicate names is returning a concatenated String separated by a `,`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using the .clone() method, using a snippet I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884362/remove-first-class-with-jquery-while-cloning)  I have adapted it slightly to support the spring form tags, by simply changing the html being cloned.

**HTML:**

```
<form:form commandName="newIngredients">
    <div id="dynamic_ingredients">
        <a id="add-ingredient" href="#">Add Another Ingredient +</a>
        <div class="ingredient_field">
            <form:input path="name"/>
            <form:input path="amount"/>
            <form:input path="unit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

**The jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //the click function does not seem to be working in the example, so I have replaced it with this.
    $(document).on('click', '.icon-delete', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    //Keep a single clone of the original
    var clonedField = $('.ingredient_field').clone(), 
    main = $('#dynamic_ingredients');

    // Add in the delete <a>
    $('<a>', {
        text: 'Remove Step', 
        class: 'icon-delete', 
        href: '#'
    }).appendTo(clonedField);

    // Clone the cloned original and append it back to the list
    $('#add-ingredient').click(function() {
        main.append(clonedField.clone());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you share your spring method?